# Connect Arduino to the Internet without the shield

Tags: c, hardware, arduino

I am doing some projects with Arduino at the moment, and I was wondering if it is possible to make HTTP requests without the Internet [shield](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoShields).

The idea was to make a program which does HTTP requests and sends the response to the Arduino over the serial port.

I did some search online, but I could not find a way how to send the response to the Arduino board.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, I've done this. I had a remote temperature logger built with an Arduino. Then I used the USB cable to connect the Arduino to a laptop. The laptop had a WiFi connection to my network and could get out to the Internet if it wanted to, but I actually just connected to my desktop.

I didn't do anything special on the Arduino other than writing to/reading from the Serial port. I had a tiny Python program on the laptop acting as a gateway to the network (read from Serial, write to port and vice versa) and another tiny Python program on my desktop to read from port and write to disk.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible also to use pyfirmata in a python web server like flask under linux to control your arduino via web interface.your arduino will commnunicate with your web server via firmata protocol

Comment: FYI, a while back I also coded [pyaler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyaler) that uses bottle.py and custom serial commands.